# Get all config options extjs

Tags: extjs

How can I get the entire list of config options for any controll type in extjs 5.1.1? I tried to use

```
var control = Ext.create({xtype: controlType});
var controlConfig = control.getConfig();
var confNames = Ext.Object.getKeys(controlConfig);
```

but it return only few options, not all.

Comment: Try component.initialConfig

Answer (score 0):

Config functions usually start with a `set` such as setWidth(100).

```
    getAllConfig: function (component) {
        let prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(component);

        return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(prototype)
            .filter(function (property) {
                return typeof component[property] == "function";
            }).filter(function (name) {
                return name !== "self" && name !== "configClass";
            }).filter(function (name) {
                return /^set[A-Z].*/.test(name);
            });
    },
```